# I want to add a phrase "the Great" before every name in list names, why this did not work?

Tags: python

```py
def make_great(names):
    great_magicians = []
    for name in names:
        great_magicians.append("the Great " + name)
    names = great_magicians
```

IDE told me that  'names' value is not used. What does this mean? how can I fix it?

Comment: Your function returns nothing and prints nothing.

Comment: You would need to `return` the new list, in order for the work you did inside the function to be any use.  Assigning it to the function's parameter has no effect outside of the function.

Comment: You did. However, assigning the resulting list to `names` accomplishes nothing. Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I don't know how to respond to the 2nd floor. it's too long, I did not finish it. I think I know the reason now. variable "names" in my function is a local variable which points to the object names, the variable cannot change the object. Is that right?

Comment: Frankly, you need a basic tutorial

Answer (score 2):

The function call should `return` the values

```
from typing import List

def make_great(names: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    great_magicians = []
    for name in names:
        great_magicians.append("the Great " + name)
    return great_magicians


the_names = make_great(['A', 'B'])
print(the_names)
```

output

```
['the Great A', 'the Great B']
```

A shorter version with same functionality:

```
the_names = [f'the Great {x}' for x in ['A', 'B']]
```

Answer (score 1):

`names` is a local reference to the list. you are setting it locally but the reference to your object is lost when the function gets out of scope.

I suggest you return `great_magicians`.

```py
def make_great(names):
    great_magicians = []
    for name in names:
        great_magicians.append("the Great " + name)
    return great_magicians
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is understanding how python passes values to functions.

In python, everything is effectively pass-by-reference. `names` is a local variable to your function, but refers to the object that was passed in.

`great_magicians` is another local variable. When you do

```
names = great_magicians
```

You are making `names` refer to something else, not changing the object that `names` used to refer to.

If you want a function that changes the list in-place, which is how you seem to be expecting your function to work, you need to modify the object:

```
def make_great(names):
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        names[i] = f"the Great {name}"
```

However, it is generally better practice to not modify your parameters, and instead just return a new object like many of the other answers suggest.

In python, I'd typically do this with a list comprehension:

```
def make_great(names):
    return [f"the Great {name}" for name in names]
```